# Change the height of a box while changing the width

Tags: html, css

I want to have a box were when I resize my windows to a smaller width, it should also change the height of that box. it is supposed to be used in a responsive site, but when I try to make it work the height only change when I actually change the height of my windows, and the results it is giving is a box with white boxes. Just for info I am also using `Transform:Translate()` to move the picture inside around. its a little hard to actually give a code, because I don't care what type of code I am using.

Comment: can you provide more information like the code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `vw` value for resizing the height of an element relative to the viewport width.

E.g.
HTML:

```
<html>
    <div>
    <div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 10vw;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ao2ey0cm/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript code to get your browser window width:

```
function getWindowWidth() {
  var myWidth = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ) )     {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth) ) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  }
  return myWidth;
}
```

Or using to handle resize window event:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $( "body" ).prepend( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + "</div>" );
  // Put your code here for resizing your element
});
```